# Which is the best correlation test for variables on the Likert scale?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, likert, scales

Which is the best test for testing correlation between a 5 Likert scale (50 questions neuroticism scale) and one 4 Likert scale (16 question burnout scale) ?

Comment: My survey item presents several ordered choices: one could correctly call it a rating item or perhaps a rating scale. What, then, is a Likert item, or a Likert scale? These are not simply synonyms for the first two terms. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale for helpful info.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on whether you want to regard the Likert scale as ordinal or interval.

Technically, it is only ordinal. We don't know that the differences between levels. So, then, you would use rank correlation. There are a bunch of these, the most common is almost certainly Spearman's $\rho$, but there is also Kendall's $\tau$ (which has at least 3 variations) and several others.

$\tau_c$ may be most appropriate, since you have two different Likert scales and $\tau_c$ works well for rectangular matrices.

But it is common to look at Likert scales as interval, despite the fact that this is not *exactly* true. For instance, many many scales involve adding a bunch of Likert items. When you add things, you are assuming they are (at least) interval level.

Then you  could use Pearson's r.

Stevens' whole "nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio" idea has been turned (by some people) from a guideline into a straitjacket. But those four levels are neither exhaustive nor exact.  Likert scales are, for practical purposes, in-between interval and ordinal. There has even been research (sorry, but I don't remember cites, I looked at this 20+ years ago) showing that the differences are approximately equal, especially when the scales are anchored.

I wrote a [blog post about this](https://medium.com/peter-flom-the-blog/nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio-stevens-typology-and-some-problems-with-it-93b1033815f7) (I hope it's OK to post ....)

Comment: @rolando2 This is a comment on my answer, but it doesn't seem to be related to my answer. And you aren't the OP of the question, so, I am wondering if you meant to put it as a comment on the question?

Comment: I did!  I've moved it.